# Bootloader issues

Tags: bootloader, boot-repair

How can I rectify booting issues when the os cannot load/ retrieve available users. When the Ubuntu loads , it only shows a black wallpaper, i.e a blank dull age instead of giving room for user to login

Comment: It's helpful if you're specific with details; is this a Ubuntu Core installation? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? and what release of the *unstated* product? Did you make changes in the last session where it worked, if so what? Have you attempted to boot using recovery console? runlevel 1? safe graphics (nomodeset etc)? Is the text system booting and you're not getting the display manager allowing login? or you're asking about a textual login?  Have you booted *live* media & perform file-system checks? etc

Comment: It is an Ubuntu Desktop, and I haven't Made any changes in the last session, I've attempted booting using recovery CLI but It doesn't work

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Can you boot recovery mode, to terminal? Second line in grub menu.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Comment: I still see no release details and your question (*what we'll answer*) still does not say Ubuntu Desktop.  The release details give us clear details of what *software stack* you're using, ie. 23.10 means the newest 2023-October stack, 22.04 the older 2022-April stack etc.